# Why arr.entries() for loop does not work in TS?

Tags: typescript

Why arr.entries() for loop does not work in TS?
this works just fine in chrome console

```
 var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
 var e = arr.entries();
 for (let [index, elem] of e) {
       debugger;
       console.log(`index = ${index}, elem = ${elem}`);
 }
```

but does not breakpoint in TypeScript 2.1.4
also I wonder why I get this error in ts:

`Error:(67, 35) TS2495:Type 'IterableIterator<[number, string]>' is not an array type or a string type.`

I can set as `:any` but obviosuly that's not the idea

regards

Sean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably targeting `es3` or `es5`, and as it [states in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html#targeting-es5-and-es3):

> When targeting an ES5 or ES3, iterators are only allowed on values of
>   Array type. It is an error to use for..of loops on non-Array values,
>   even if these non-Array values implement the Symbol.iterator property.

If you target `es6` it should compile with no errors.

Comment: I compiled your exact code with targeting `es6` and it went fine. Are you compiling the same code you posted or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Building on Nitzan Tomer's answer, this code would work with `es5`:

```
 var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
 for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
     let elem = arr[index];
     console.log(`index = ${index}, elem = ${elem}`);
 }
```

Enjoy.

Comment: yes tx, ya I know but was trying to avoid the extra assignment, otherwise I would just use _.forEach(....

Comment: @born2net there's a native `forEach` method for js arrays, no need to use `_.forEach` in any case.

Comment: agreed, yes, tx as always... (just so used to _... :)

Answer (score 0):

tx for the help, targeting es6 did it!